# maximize listview when form window is strteched at runtime

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am using vb.net, I have created a form and there are two listviews in that form which are getting filled by button event. Every thing is going smooth, but the problem is when my exeute my project and in the form, when I maximize the form window(by clicking maximize button provided in the top right corner) the size  of listview remains same while form maximizes, this looks odd, what i need is to maximize the listview also with the increase in the form window size.

I searched in google a lot and i found one property 'dock' of listview which i can set left, full, right,bottom,top or none, but this doesn't serve my purpose.

Snapshot when I am using Anchor property
On Starting:
[image: Image1]

After Maximizing:
[image: Image2]
Please guide me in the right direction, what I need to do

when no propety is set then image on maximizing is:
[image]
Thank you

With Regards

Comment: show a screen shot actual what happening ??

Comment: @WingedPanther Image Added

Comment: set anchor for `ListView` in _LEFT SIDE_ as {left,bottom,top} and set anchor for `ListView` in _RIGHT SIDE_ as {right,bottom,top}

Comment: I used pannel and did the same thing, not wokring and set `nchor for ListView in LEFT SIDE as {left,bottom,top} and set anchor for ListView in RIGHT SIDE as {right,bottom,top}` also not working

Comment: second method should work

Comment: or is that really necessary to `Maximize` that form for an end user :D ??

Comment: try these things also 1.) for both listviews set anchor {bottom,top},2.) disable all anchors for both listviews

Comment: :D it looks odd when someone maximizes form, i never worked in vb.net but i have seen many applications in which this is possible. is there any way that i can edit on maximiza button click event.

Comment: on your `Form_load` event put `Me.MaximizeBox = False`

Comment: :P is this the solution or prevention :D :P

Answer (score 0):

Better than Dock property, you have to use "Anchor" property. All controls on the Form has Anchor Top,Left by default, but you can change it in the property window or directly by code. You can know more about anchor on this site: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets13p1.html

Anchoring two Listviews on a form depends on the form design, but SplitContainer control will be really usefull if you want that both Listview changes the size on form resize.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Anchor is better is dock but it is still not serving my purpose, what is happening is that two listviews are overlapping each other if I am setting anchor and I am also having two buttons and those two buttons comes over the listview and there position remains unchanged, On resizing form button should move down

Comment: and listview should increase, i know this is possible to do but what i  dont know is what is this called and how to do this

Comment: If you have two Listviews as columns, I recommend you for use a SliptContainer. Insert the container on your form, and, inside the container, one Listview on the left and the other one on the right.  Then set the SplitContainer anchor to Top, Bottom, Left, Right. Be carefull because SplitContainer usually has the Dock property to Fill when added to the Form (set it to None first)