# Inheriting class of one form to another form class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have two form windows `form1.vb` and `form2.vb`. My code so far:

```
'form1.vb
class form1
    function print(byval i as integer) as boolean
End class

'form2.vb
class form2
    inherits form1
end class
```

The code can not compile and it is showing the following error: `Error 1 Base class 'form1' specified for class 'form2' cannot be different from the base class`.

Is there any way to inherit one class from one form to another class of another form as I am writting some common functions which I dont want  to rewrite every where?

Please guide me in correct direction.

Comment: @winged Panther: problem is with inheritance.. i wanted to know how to inherit. access is later thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*goto* > `Form2.Designer.vb` and change

```
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

to
    `Inherits WindowsApplication1.Form1`  or `Inherits Form1`

Comment: is `Form2.Designer.vb` means `Form2.vb[Design]` page ?? I am using visual studio 2010 and from where I have to make change in `Inherits WindowsApplication1.Form1 or Inherits Form1` in the property, I am not able to find it.

Comment: @avinashse yes it's the designer.vb  and you have to find out `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form` and change it to `Inherits WindowsApplication1.Form1`(if not worked then `Inherits Form1`) :: NOTE:: am using `VS2008`

Comment: @avinashse it's available below the line `Partial Class Form2` in `Form2.Designer.vb`

Comment: @avinashse > see this [View Designer Code in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099694/view-designer-code-in-visual-studio-2010)

Comment: Thank you sir not just for telling me how to inherit but also for telling me about `MODULE`, it is also very useful.

Comment: i have one more question `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25821234/maximize-listview-when-form-window-is-strteched-at-runtime/25821520#25821520`  It will be very helpful is you can see that also :)